# Does OpenEBS support arm64 architecture?

Tags: kubernetes, arm64, nextcloud, openebs

Is there any development for the arm64 support for openebs? Github link show this will support in 0.6 version. Does any private repo from that blog post or do you have official arm64 support now?  I have 4 Pine64 at home (1 master, 3 nodes with k8s 1.11.3) with the nodes having a 2 TB usb disk attached each. I would like to use OpenEBS for provisioning persistent volumes for my own Nextcloud installation.

Answer (score 1):

OpenEBS supports multi arch builds for all the images from 2.0.0 release onwards https://hub.docker.com/search?q=openebs&type=image

Answer (score 0):

Experimental version is available if you like and instructions are described here in the [blog link](http://containerized.me/arming-kubernetes-with-openebs-1/) to install OpenEBS on arm64. Build available on the article should work on Pine64.
Currently arm64 is not included in build setup, official support is planned post v.1.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

Well its been couple of years and now its OpenEBS is 2.2.0. still no arm64 support :D actually none of the native storage support arm64 without hacking and compiling stuff so there are two solutions only NFS and Gluster which works for sure and without hassle... There is a chance that Longhorn as only one I could find will officaly release support for arm64 this week https://github.com/longhorn/longhorn/issues/6